# Non measurable set .

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $C$ be a circle of circumference $1$, and let a be an irrational
number. Let all points of C which can be obtained from each other by
rotating C through an angle nax (where n is any integer, positive, negative
or zero) be assigned to the same class.

Let $\phi_0$ be any set containing one point from each class. Prove that $\phi_0$ is non measurable.

First $\phi_n$  be the set obtained by rotating $\phi_0$ through the angle $n\alpha\pi$. Then $$C=\cup_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi_n $$ and  $$\phi_m \  n \ \phi_n = \emptyset , \ (m \neq n )$$

If $\phi_0$ were measurable, the congruent sets $\phi_n$ would also be measurable.

But now I'm stuck here, How can I prove that this would imply 
$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mu{(\phi_n)} = 1 $$.

But congruent sets must have the same measure, i.e, if $\phi_0$ were measurable, then $$ \mu{(\phi_0)} = \mu{(\phi_n)}$$ which contradicts that $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mu{(\phi_n)} = 1 $$.

If someone could help me to prove this,I'm really stuck now and I can't prove that this set is non measurable.

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Countable additivity of Lebesgue measure: if $\phi_n$ are disjoint and measurable, $\mu\left(\bigcup_n \phi_n\right) = \sum_n \mu(\phi_n)$

Comment: With this Can I complete the proof?

Comment: Why this is true I feel that this is wrong , if $\phi_0$ were measurable, then $$ \mu{(\phi_0)} = \mu{(\phi_n)}$$ which contradicts that $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mu{(\phi_n)} = 1 $$. ?